# Get The Full Word Containing % In String

Tags: php, regex

Here's the string:

$title = "Get 20% Off";

Here's the code which isn't working in case of %

```
$re = '~(?=(?:\S*[^\w\s]){2,})\S+~'; 
$str = "Get 20% Off== FG"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

I want to get the word 20%

Comment: what is other sentence example ?

Comment: Check this example : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aca4648046df083f2b851820e1cf51e55be50398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$re = '(\d+(\.\d+)?%)'; 
$str = "Get 20% Off== FG"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 20% )
```